# Java BufferedImage get single pixel brightness

Tags: java, image, monochrome

I want to convert coloured image to a monochrome, i thought to loop all pixel, but I don't know how to test if they are bright or dark.

```
        for(int y=0;y<image.getHeight();y++){
            for(int x=0;x<image.getWidth();x++){
                int color=image.getRGB(x, y);
                // ???how to test if its is bright or dark?
            }
        }
```

Comment: It depends on what you mean with "light" and "dark". Maybe setting a threshold could help?

Comment: How can I set a threshold?

Comment: Note that there are simpler ways than manually going through all the pixels: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14513542/convert-image-to-black-white/14514294#14514294

Answer (score 8, accepted):

```
int color = image.getRGB(x, y);

// extract each color component
int red   = (color >>> 16) & 0xFF;
int green = (color >>>  8) & 0xFF;
int blue  = (color >>>  0) & 0xFF;

// calc luminance in range 0.0 to 1.0; using SRGB luminance constants
float luminance = (red * 0.2126f + green * 0.7152f + blue * 0.0722f) / 255;

// choose brightness threshold as appropriate:
if (luminance >= 0.5f) {
    // bright color
} else {
    // dark color
}
```

Comment: how to implement this to get the whole image's luminance?, sum and divide?

Comment: @ZOLDIK Yup. Simple average.

Answer (score 2):

I suggest first converting the pixel to grayscale, then applying a threshold for converting it pure black&white.

There are libraries that will do this for you, but if you want to learn how images are processed, here you are:

## Colour to grayscale

There are various formulas for converting (see a nice article [here](http://www.johndcook.com/blog/2009/08/24/algorithms-convert-color-grayscale/)), I prefer the "luminosity" one. So:

```
int grayscalePixel = (0.21 * pRed) + (0.71 * pGreen) + (0.07 * pBlue)
```

I cannot tell what API you are using to manipulate the image, so I left the formula above in general terms. `pRed`, `pGreen` and `pBlue` are the red, green and blue levels (values) for the pixel.

## Grayscale to b/w

Now, you can apply a threshold with:

```
int bw = grayscalePixel > THRESHOLD? 1: 0;
```

or even:

```
boolean bw = grayscalePixel > THRESHOLD;
```

Pixel will be white if above threshold, black if below. Find the right `THRESHOLD` by experimenting a bit.