# Using pdfbox to convert a color PDF to a b/w tiff

Tags: pdf, pdfbox, tiff, image-conversion

I am have a bit of a problem converting some color PDFs to tiff images. The PDFs I am having problems with have hand written signatures written in blue ink. These signatures do not appear in the generated binary tiffs. I suspect there is a threshold value somewhere to determine which pixels will be black and which will be white.

```
@SuppressWarnings("serial")
private static void convertPdfToTiff(final File pdf, final File tif) throws Exception {
    try 
    {
        final Iterator<ImageWriter> imageWriterIterator = ImageIO.getImageWritersByFormatName("TIF");
        final ImageWriter imageWriter = imageWriterIterator.hasNext() ? imageWriterIterator.next() : null;

        final TIFFImageWriteParam writeParam = new TIFFImageWriteParam(Locale.getDefault());
        writeParam.setCompressionMode(TIFFImageWriteParam.MODE_EXPLICIT);
        writeParam.setCompressionType("LZW");

        PDDocument pdfDocument = PDDocument.load(pdf);
        PDFRenderer pdfRenderer = new PDFRenderer(pdfDocument);

        OutputStream out = new FileOutputStream(tif);
        final BufferedOutputStream bufferedOutputStream = new BufferedOutputStream(out);
        final ImageOutputStream imageOutputStream = ImageIO.createImageOutputStream(bufferedOutputStream);
        imageWriter.setOutput(imageOutputStream);
        imageWriter.prepareWriteSequence(null);

        int pageCounter = 0;
        for (PDPage page : pdfDocument.getPages()) 
        {
            BufferedImage image = pdfRenderer.renderImageWithDPI(pageCounter, 300, ImageType.BINARY);

            final IIOImage s = new IIOImage(image, null, new TIFFImageMetadata(new TIFFIFD(new Vector<BaselineTIFFTagSet>() 
            {
                {
                       add(BaselineTIFFTagSet.getInstance());
                }
            }))) 

            {   
                {
                       final TIFFImageMetadata tiffMetadata = (TIFFImageMetadata) getMetadata();
                       final TIFFIFD rootIFD = tiffMetadata.getRootIFD();
                       final BaselineTIFFTagSet base = BaselineTIFFTagSet.getInstance();
                       rootIFD.addTIFFField(new TIFFField(base.getTag(BaselineTIFFTagSet.TAG_X_RESOLUTION), TIFFTag.TIFF_RATIONAL, 1, new long[][] { { 300, 1 } }));
                       rootIFD.addTIFFField(new TIFFField(base.getTag(BaselineTIFFTagSet.TAG_Y_RESOLUTION), TIFFTag.TIFF_RATIONAL, 1, new long[][] { { 300, 1 } }));
                }
            };

            imageWriter.writeToSequence(s, writeParam);
            pageCounter++;
        }

        imageWriter.dispose();
        imageOutputStream.flush();
        imageOutputStream.close();
        bufferedOutputStream.flush();
        bufferedOutputStream.close();
        pdfDocument.close();
        out.flush();
        out.close();
    } 
    catch (Exception e) 
    {
        e.printStackTrace();
        throw e;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I had the same problem (blue signatures) some time ago and I did this:

- render to RGB
- convert to b/w with a filter from [JH Labs](http://www.jhlabs.com/ip/filters/index.html) (I got pointed to this by a comment in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14513542/convert-image-to-black-white))
- I initially tried the dither and the diffusion filter
- the filter that worked best for me was the bias part (I think I used 0.3) of the [gain filter](http://www.jhlabs.com/ip/filters/GainFilter.html) combined with the [diffusion filter](http://www.jhlabs.com/ip/filters/DiffusionFilter.html).
- you can combine two filters with the [compound filter](http://www.jhlabs.com/ip/filters/CompoundFilter.html).
- the jhlabs stuff is not available as .jar file, but you can download the sources and add it to your project
- [some examples](http://www.programcreek.com/java-api-examples/index.php?api=com.jhlabs.image.BoxBlurFilter)

Btw, save your files not as LZW, but as G4, that'll make them smaller. PDFBox has methods to efficiently save into images, see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23326562/apache-pdfbox-convert-pdf-to-images). `ImageIOUtil.writeImage()` will save to G4 compressed TIFF if your BufferedImage is of type BITONAL.

Comment: Thanks for the response. That gave me the idea of rendering the image as ImageType.GRAY while create a new binary bufferedimage and drawing the gray image into the new binary image.

Answer (score 0):

I ended up rendering the image as grayscale and re drawing it to a second bw image.

```
@SuppressWarnings("serial")
private static void convertPdfToTiff(final File pdf, final File tif) throws Exception {
    try 
    {
        final Iterator<ImageWriter> imageWriterIterator = ImageIO.getImageWritersByFormatName("TIF");
        final ImageWriter imageWriter = imageWriterIterator.hasNext() ? imageWriterIterator.next() : null;

        final TIFFImageWriteParam writeParam = new TIFFImageWriteParam(Locale.getDefault());
        writeParam.setCompressionMode(TIFFImageWriteParam.MODE_EXPLICIT);
        writeParam.setCompressionType("CCITT T.6");

        PDDocument pdfDocument = PDDocument.load(pdf);
        PDFRenderer pdfRenderer = new PDFRenderer(pdfDocument);

        OutputStream out = new FileOutputStream(tif);
        final BufferedOutputStream bufferedOutputStream = new BufferedOutputStream(out);
        final ImageOutputStream imageOutputStream = ImageIO.createImageOutputStream(bufferedOutputStream);
        imageWriter.setOutput(imageOutputStream);
        imageWriter.prepareWriteSequence(null);

        int pageCounter = 0;
        for (PDPage page : pdfDocument.getPages()) 
        {
            BufferedImage image = pdfRenderer.renderImageWithDPI(pageCounter, 300, ImageType.GRAY);
            BufferedImage image2 = new BufferedImage(image.getWidth(), image.getHeight(), BufferedImage.TYPE_BYTE_BINARY);
            Graphics2D g = image2.createGraphics();
            g.drawRenderedImage(image, null);
            g.dispose();

            final IIOImage s = new IIOImage(image2, null, new TIFFImageMetadata(new TIFFIFD(new Vector<BaselineTIFFTagSet>() 
            {
                {
                       add(BaselineTIFFTagSet.getInstance());
                }
            }))) 

            {   
                {
                       final TIFFImageMetadata tiffMetadata = (TIFFImageMetadata) getMetadata();
                       final TIFFIFD rootIFD = tiffMetadata.getRootIFD();
                       final BaselineTIFFTagSet base = BaselineTIFFTagSet.getInstance();
                       rootIFD.addTIFFField(new TIFFField(base.getTag(BaselineTIFFTagSet.TAG_X_RESOLUTION), TIFFTag.TIFF_RATIONAL, 1, new long[][] { { 300, 1 } }));
                       rootIFD.addTIFFField(new TIFFField(base.getTag(BaselineTIFFTagSet.TAG_Y_RESOLUTION), TIFFTag.TIFF_RATIONAL, 1, new long[][] { { 300, 1 } }));
                }
            };

            imageWriter.writeToSequence(s, writeParam);
            pageCounter++;
        }

        imageWriter.dispose();
        imageOutputStream.flush();
        imageOutputStream.close();
        bufferedOutputStream.flush();
        bufferedOutputStream.close();
        pdfDocument.close();
        out.flush();
        out.close();
    } 
    catch (Exception e) 
    {
        e.printStackTrace();
        throw e;
    }
}
```